# Defining class which is part of another class in a different file

Tags: c++, class, struct, header

Consider following code:

```
class App{
    public:
    struct A{
        int foo;
    };
    struct B{
        double bar;
    };
};
```

What would be the appropriate way to define classes A and B in **separate** header files (e.g. a.h & b.h) and then include them in the `class App` so they are parts of it?

Comment: By doing what you wrote? I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. Did you try this? Was there a particular problem?

Comment: There was not a problem with what I wrote but I have dummed down this code, in reality my structs A and B were lot bigger with their specific methods and such and it would've helped readability of my code if I just had those definitions in different files.

Comment: And what was preventing you from doing it like this?

Comment: Plenty of code (that someone who is meant to use class App should not care about) wasting space. I am just a beginner anyway and maybe I am looking too much into this for now, but anyhow, would it be a bad practice to put the #include directives right in the middle of the class definition?

Answer (score 0):

Just move them into the separate headers. Use header guards to protect against the individual headers being included separately as well as from the `app.h` header. And assign names to the struct members.

`a.h`

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

struct A {
    int foo;
};

#endif
```

`b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct B {
    int bar;
};

#endif
```

`app.h`:

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

class App {
    public:
    A a;
    B b;
};

#endif
```

Comment: I don't neccessarily need the instances of objects of type A and B directly in class App.

Comment: You specifically said **and then include them in the class App so they are parts of it**

Answer (score 0):

Only way to define a nested class is to have the definition inside the other. Technically, the language doesn't prevent the definition from being included from another file:

```
// outer.hpp
#pragma once    

struct outer
{
#include "inner.hpp"
};

// inner.hpp
struct inner {

};
```

However, this it is quite unconventional to include a file into any other scope than the global namespace, and I recommend against doing this.

What I do recommend is to reconsider whether there is benefit in one class being nested inside the other. If there is, then it would be best to accept that it will be a long definition.

Comment: Ok this seems to have covered all of the question marks I had. Can you elaborate more on including file into namespace different than the global?